# How can I set cascade delete when I create tables on MySQL with Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot.

Currently, I need to set Cascade Delete property on my table which I am about create for my Spring Boot Project.

Below is my java code which defines the table "MESSAGE".

The table "MESSAGE" has two foreign keys ( "Header", "MessageBody" )

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="MESSAGE")
public class LSportsMessage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HEADER_ID")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Header")
    private Header header;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BODY_ID")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="MessageBody")
    private MessageBody messageBody;

    @Column(name = "IS_INPLAY")
    private Boolean isInplay = false;

    @Column(name = "IS_PREMATCH")
    private Boolean isPrematch = false;

}
```

The creation of DB is half successful since when I run SHOW CREATE TABLE `MESSAGE`, below output is displayed.

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `message_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_inplay` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_prematch` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `header_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
  KEY `FK10f5dp8hyhqi35fn83goqkxpk` (`header_id`),
  KEY `FK3dpoffc04evqxd8d2kieghiol` (`body_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK10f5dp8hyhqi35fn83goqkxpk` FOREIGN KEY (`header_id`) REFERENCES `header` (`header_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK3dpoffc04evqxd8d2kieghiol` FOREIGN KEY (`body_id`) REFERENCES `body` (`body_id`)
)
```

No where of output mentions the cascade delete.

How can I fix this?

I really need row in "Header" and "MessageBody" Table to be deleted automatically when I delete corresponding row in table "Message".

Answer (score 1):

```
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HEADER_ID")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Header")
    private Header header;
```

You can have multiple Cascade condition including
ALL | PERSIST | MERGE | REMOVE | REFRESH | DETACH

additionally, Hibernate Cascade options specifically supported by hibernate:

REPLICATE | SAVE_UPDATE | LOCK

Comment: My code already contains REMOVE attribute since I declared CascadeType.ALL.
Isn't it so?

Comment: CacadeType.ALL Includes CacadeType.REMOVE and CacadeType.DETACH so selecting specific will help.

Comment: In my many-to-one case, it is not working.